# the right syntax - minimum value

Tags: excel, powerquery

what is the correct syntax to get the minimum value ? I need the Minimum value between these two :

```
Duration.Days(Date.EndOfMonth(ay) - [#"Date of Employment (Work)"])
Date.Day(Date.EndOfMonth(ay))
```

i tried List.Min but it gave error

```
We cannot convert the value 699 to type List.
```

i also tried but no such function as "MIN"

```
MIN(Duration.Days(Date.EndOfMonth(ay) - [#"Date of Employment (Work)"])
    ,Date.Day(Date.EndOfMonth(ay)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List.Min` will work, if you pass a *list* as the first argument:

```
List.Min(
    {
        Duration.Days(Date.EndOfMonth(ay) - [#"Date of Employment (Work)"]),
        Date.Day(Date.EndOfMonth(ay))
    }
)
```

Notice I wrapped your two functions in `{ }`, to make them a list.